# Sentence returns empty dictionary from gensim.corpora

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, spacy

I'm trying to modify an example from [this post](http://dsgeek.com/2018/02/19/tfidf_vectors.html)
that applies tf-idf.

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from gensim.corpora import Dictionary
from gensim.models.tfidfmodel import TfidfModel
from gensim.matutils import sparse2full
import numpy as np
import spacy

nlp  = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')


def keep_token(t):
    return (t.is_alpha and 
            not (t.is_space or t.is_punct or 
                 t.is_stop or t.like_num))

def lemmatize_doc(doc):
    return [ t.lemma_ for t in doc if keep_token(t)]

sentences = ['Pro USB and Analogue Microphone']
docs = [lemmatize_doc(nlp(doc)) for doc in sentences]
docs_dict = Dictionary(docs)
docs_dict.filter_extremes(no_below=20, no_above=0.2)
docs_dict.compactify()
docs_corpus = [docs_dict.doc2bow(doc) for doc in docs]
model_tfidf = TfidfModel(docs_corpus, id2word=docs_dict)
docs_tfidf  = model_tfidf[docs_corpus]
docs_vecs   = np.vstack([sparse2full(c, len(docs_dict)) for c in docs_tfidf])
tfidf_emb_vecs = np.vstack([nlp(docs_dict[i]).vector for i in range(len(docs_dict))])
docs_emb = np.dot(docs_vecs, tfidf_emb_vecs) 


But I'm getting this error: 

   282     _warn_for_nonsequence(tup)
--> 283     return _nx.concatenate([atleast_2d(_m) for _m in tup], 0)
    284 
    285 

ValueError: need at least one array to concatenate
```

The reason is that this line is retuning an empty list:

```
docs_corpus = [docs_dict.doc2bow(doc) for doc in docs]
docs_corpus
```

This is because the dictionary is empty:

[image]

But I'm feeding the dic with a non empty list

[image]

That's the part I'm not finding the reason for which it fails

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this line:

```
docs_dict.filter_extremes(no_below=20, no_above=0.2)
```

`no_below=20` means that all tokens with a count of less than 20 in the whole corpus will be deleted from the dictionary. 
`no_above=0.2` means that all tokens that occur in more than 20 percent of your documents will be deleted from the dictionary. 
Since you only used a toy document set for the example, all of your tokens will be filtered. Just comment the line while using the toy document set.

Comment: Ya, its perfectly working, and one thing this depends on our data?

Comment: @HackbalTeamz Correct. The `filter_extremes` function is most useful for large datasets, e.g. when you would run out of memory while creating your models. It doesn't make too much sense for small data sets imo.